# Strange behavior with svg circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I saw this cool transition for the circles in an image slider (the ones showing you what picture you're up to) on [Stripe.com](https://stripe.com/) and I decided to try duplicating it. *This only seems to work on Chrome and Opera*

My attempt went decently enough, but there's one bug that seems inexplicable. When clicking on the last circle, any circle that previously had been filled will sort of fade out.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wwr6k7b/1/)

Relevant HTML:

```
 <li class="coolBubble selected" onclick="jump_to_position(0)" id="bubble0">
    <svg width="10" height="10" >
        <defs>
            <mask id="center-mask">
                <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#fff"></circle>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <circle fill="none" stroke="rgb(35,0,0)" stroke-width="1" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" mask="url(#center-mask)"></circle>
    </svg>
</li>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
       .coolBubble circle {

            stroke: rgb(35, 0, 0);
            transition: stroke-width 300ms ease-in-out;
        }

        .selected circle {
            stroke-width: 8px;
        }
```

Relevant JS:

```
function jump_to_position(newIndex) {

    if (currIndex === newIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    var currBubble = '#bubble' + (currIndex);
    var newBubble = '#bubble' + (newIndex);

    $(currBubble).removeClass('selected');
    $(newBubble).addClass('selected');

    currIndex = newIndex;

}
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique within a document. All the `mask`s in the fiddle have the same `id`.

Comment: After testing for quite a While, the problem seems to be with this property of .coolBubble circle -> `stroke: rgb(35, 0, 0);` by removing it, everything works fine, I'm not sure why this stroke is screwing it up by the way, but maybe we can actually find a workaround, can't we? (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wwr6k7b/3/). The ID thing however is.. Idk, lol.

Comment: @Teemu good catch, but weirdly when I make the masks unique, it breaks completely and displays squares instead of circles.

Comment: @briosheje Very cool catch. I'm going to play around with that. I apparently don't even need that line in, so I may as well take it out. Wonder why it does that though...

Comment: What actually is "center-mask"? I mean, why does it have this ID? I'm not understanding why by giving it a class instead of an ID it is completely screwing the circle :P

Comment: @briosheje I honestly have no idea lol.

Comment: Oh, okay. Anyway I think I've found a workaround for that: You can just define the stroke to the circle instead of giving it from the CSS file. Let me try this.. I'll update the fiddle soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63947/discussion-between-general-twyckenham-and-briosheje).